# Как приостановить UI поток на время выполнения Task

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Добрый день.
Запутался с многопоточностью.
Пишу приложение на winforms.По нажатию кнопки запускается метод, который выполняет длительную работу. По окончании работы метода хочу вывести сообщение что готово.
Однако сообщение выпадает сразу.

Код обработчика:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
       openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory=System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("С:\\");
       openFileDialog1.Filter = "Log Files |*.log";
       if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            DestinationPath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
        else return;
        Action action = () => new  ParcerVMManager(DestinationPath).StartParcer();
        Task task1 = new Task(action);
        task1.Start();
         task1.Wait();
     MessageBox.Show("Запись в БД окончена");
   }
```

Метод StartParcer тоже асинхронный.

```
 public async void StartParcer()
    {
        using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(destinationPath))
        {
            while (true)
            {
               string temp = fs.ReadLine();
               if (temp == null) break;
               await Task.Run(() =>LogStringHandler(temp));
            }
        }
        foreach (var item in ParcedData)
        {
            if(! repo.CheckDuplicate(new LogDataVMBuilder().GetModel(item))) continue;
            else
            {
              item.UnloadedFile.Title = GetTitle(item);
              await  GetNameByIP(item);
            }
        }
         await WriteToDB();

        return;
    }
```

Может быть такая ситуация происходит из-за того что я намешал в одном методе и `async/await` и `Task` ? Но как быть в таком случае, когда мне нужно  асинхронно выполнить методы `GetNameByIP(item);`   `await WriteToDB();`?

Comment: Зачем останавливать ui поток?

Comment: Зачем вам выполнять их асинхронно если вы все равно хотите приостановить поток?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы сообщение "Запись в БД окончена" выводилась после окончания записи. А у меня она выводится сразу по нажатию кнопки.

Comment: Или не останавливайте UI поток, или откажитесь от асинхронности.

Comment: @ Pavel Mayorov  То есть, чтобы получит сообщение об окончании записи вовремя, мне нужно синхронно вызвать StartParcer(), а уже внутри него асинхронно вызывать GetNameByIP(item);  await WriteToDB(); и др?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UI-поток приостанавливать нельзя, т. к. на время приостановки UI-потока ваше приложение подвиснет.

Вы должны просто дождаться результата *асинхронно*:

```
await new ParcerVMManager(DestinationPath).StartParcer();
MessageBox.Show("Запись в БД окончена");
```

Для этого метод `button1_Click` превратите в `async`: `private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`, а также поменяйте возвращаемый тип  `StartParcer` на `Task`: `public async Task StartParcer()`.

---

Если ваш метод `StartParcer` окажется медленным (а он делает много синхронной работы, например, синхронно читает файл), вынесите его тоже в фоновый поток:

```
// локальная переменная нужна, если свойство DestinationPath привязано к потоку
var destinationPathLocal = DestinationPath;
await Task.Run(() => new ParcerVMManager(destinationPathLocal).StartParcer());
```

---

Ваша проблема на самом деле нетривиальна. Смотрите, ваш `action` запускает `StartParser`, но поскольку это асинхронный метод, то `action` не дожидается его окончания. Далее, ваш `Task task1` занимается тем, что запускает `action`. То есть, `Task task1` запускает таск `StartParser`. Соответственно ваш `Wait` дожидается лишь *запуска* `StartParser`, а не его окончания.

Дополнительное чтение по теме: [Stephen Toub, *Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/).

Comment: Сейчас попробую. Это не сильно отличается от того, что я пробовал вчера, но попробую.

Comment: StartParcer() очень медленный. Он и файл обрабатывает и  из сети данные тянет и в базу пишет. С нормальным (не тестовым файлом) он работать будет минут 10 наверное. Точнее не он сам, но методы, которые он вызывает

Comment: Спасибо. Ваш вариант работает.

Comment: @foxhound: Пожалуйста, рад, если помогло!